# SELECT * from a table but add conditional to one column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible in PostgreSQL to `SELECT *` from a table, but add a condition to one column in that result and overwrite it? I'll explain easier with a code example of what I'm trying to do (pseudo code)

```
SELECT
  *,
  CASE
    WHEN column_name=1 THEN 'one'
    WHEN column_name=2 THEN 'two'
    ELSE 'other'
  END AS column_name
FROM table
```

and this returns something like:

```
id | name  | column_name | created_at
------------------------------------
1  | Title | one         | 123456789
```

So basically, I want to get every column without having to type each column out, but specifically alter the value of one column in the result based on some condition.

**=== UPDATE ======**

A little more clarification on what I am doing.

I'm writing a plpgsql function that returns a type of, for the above example `RETURNS schema.table`. This is then (via Postgraphile) accessed through a GraphQL endpoint and returned to our app, that is all typed with TypeScript using codegen.

So in essence, the column name needs to be 1. the same name and 2. not an alias name, as Postgraphile/GraphQL won't know this value so will be omitted.

**=== UPDATE 2 ======**

Ok I have done it now, but a different way. I looked at it and realised there is a easier way for me to do this, and why I never did it in the first place I don't know. I won't mark this resolved though, as my answer doesn't answer this question.

To get around this, I simply return my resultset into a varaible and alter this before returning:

```
SELECT schema.table.* INTO cached_data
...
IF cached_data.column_name = 'something' THEN 
  cached_data.column_name = 'something-else';
END IF;
RETURN cached_data;
```

This works perfectly for my situation.

Comment: You should explicitly specify all columns in the query *anyway*. If you are using SSMS to write the query, note you can drag the 'columns' node from the object explorer into the query window to build a select list containing all column names without typing if laziness is your only reason for not wanting to type each column out

Comment: little hint as this is pseudo code not sure what you are doing but the best is to avoid alias names which uses the same name as a table column

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use `*`, specify the table (alias if necessary)

```
SELECT
  t1.*,
  CASE
    WHEN column_name=1 THEN 'one'
    WHEN column_name=2 THEN 'two'
    ELSE 'other'
  END AS column_name
FROM table t1
```

This will return all columns from `table`, plus the new column. If you want to replace that column from `table`, explicitly state all required columns.

Note: If column_name is already a column in the table, then you will get two columns in the result set with the same name using this approach (HT @Milney)

Comment: Note: If column_name is already a column in the table, then you will get two columns in the result set with the same name using this approach

Comment: *"Note: If column_name is already a column in the table, then you will get two columns in the result set with the same name using this approach "* @Milney i would worry more about using aliases or using fully qualified table names so the optimizer cannot makes mistake if it's a column name or a alias.. something like [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sdZZguLd9J6aJabJegWxrE/0) especially when delived table (subqeury) are involved which is not in this case but still.. I still thing the best is to avoid alias names which uses the same name as a table column

Comment: Thats the problem, I don't want a duplicate and the name must match as it gets returned as a type that then gets output to my GraphQL typings. So I want all columns in the table, but just want to override the value of one column but must keep the same name

Comment: @keogh then you need to explicitly state the column names in the `select`

Answer (score 0):

You can give a nickname to your table and use TABLE_ NICKNAME.* as follow:

```
SELECT t.*,
   CASE id
     WHEN 1 THEN 'one'
     WHEN 2 THEN 'two'
     ELSE 'other'
   END AS column_name
FROM your_table t
```